# Is there an android equivalent for S60 platform's LandmarkStore

Tags: android, geolocation, android-intent, location

S60 platform's Java environment has a LandmarkStore class which saves Landmarks. A Landmark is just an object that gives a name to a location. Similar to a waypoint in GPS devices. Basic idea in S60 platform is that LandmarkStore is accessible to every application on the device. For instance, I can create a new Landmark on one Java application and this new landmark can be used in all Java applications on this device.

Is there a similar common-to-all-applications location store in Android platform? Or do I just have to ask the user to give coordinates of Home, Office and Pablo's pub when installing my location aware application?

Am I totally lost, or shouldn't the Intent system be able to provide locations for my application?

Comment: That is theoretically possible, but someone must have created an app to listen to your intents and return to you locations.  I don't think there is anything built in to do that. So, the user would need to have both that app and your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a similar common-to-all-applications location store in Android platform?

No, sorry.

> Or do I just have to ask the user to give coordinates of Home, Office and Pablo's pub when installing my location aware application?

Yes.

Comment: After checking you out I'm confident that you know what you are talking about. Thanks.